# Select Using linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

How can i use this query with linq. EmployeeIDs  is another table.

```
select * 
from Employees where EmployeeID  
in  (select ID from EmployeeIDs where ID between 3 and 7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result= (
        from e in db.Employees
        where
            (
                from eId in db.EmployeeIDs
                where eId.ID>=3 && eId.ID<=7
                select eId.ID
            ).Contains(e.EmployeeID)
        select e
    );
```

Where db is the linq data context

or you can also do it like this:

```
var result= db.Employees.Where(a=>a.EmployeeID>=3 && a.EmployeeID<=7);
```

or you can also do it like this:

```
var result= (
            from e in db.Employees
            where
                (
                    from eId in db.EmployeeIDs
                    where eId.ID>=3 && eId.ID<=7
                    && e.EmployeeID==eId.ID
                    select eId.ID
                ).Any()
            select e
        );
```

Comment: i use first one and i get error in this part   .Contains(e.EmployeeID)

Comment: not seeing what you're seeing ? the second (lambda example) or the second condition ?

Comment: @Mahdijokar: what is the type of ID in EmployeeIDs and the EmployeeID in Employees? I updated the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a join:

```
var query = from emp in employees
            join empId in employeeIds.Where(x => x.ID >= 3 && x.Id <= 7)
              on emp.EmployeeID equals empID
            select emp;
```

That's if you *really* need two tables. On the other hand, if you can assume that there will always be a valid ID in `employeeIds` for any `employee.ID` then you can just use:

```
var query = employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID >= 3 && x.EmployeeID <= 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well even in SQL, that nested `SELECT` in the `IN` statement is redundant.

You could just write

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Employees 
WHERE EmployeeID Between 3 and 7
```

In SQL `Between 3 AND 7` is just syntactic sugar for `Column >= 3 and Column <= 7`

So you could write the following against your EF Context.

```
var results = from e in context.Employees
              where EmployeeId >= 3 && EmployeeId <= 7
              select e;
```

Comment: Actually, if for example employee #4 *does not have a row in EmployeeIDs*, he won't show up in the original query, but he will in yours.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty short and straight forward using a join;

```
from emp in db.Employees
join eid in db.EmployeeIDs on emp.EmployeeID equals eid.ID
where emp.EmployeeID >= 3 && emp.EmployeeID <= 7
select emp
```

This will also result in pretty sane and straight forward SQL without nested selects (edited for readability)

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees AS emp
INNER JOIN EmployeeIDs AS eid ON emp.EmployeeID = eid.ID
WHERE (emp.EmployeeID >= 3) AND (emp.EmployeeID <= 7)
```